# SQL query using aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

Taking the following table EXAMPLE:

```
Name  |  List |  FlagByList
---------------------------
  A   |   1   |   Y
  A   |   2   |   Y
  B   |   1   |   Y
  B   |   2   |   N
  C   |   -   |   -
  C   |   -   |   -
```

I want to return the Names which have 'Y' in all Lists AND the Names which are not present in any list.

Comment: Show us the expected result, and your current query attempt!

Comment: Can you have the situation where you have both `A,1,Y` and `A,1,N` in the table? What would be the expected result in this case (i.e. include as it has `Y` for that list or exclude as not all the values are `Y`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple aggregate query can do this.

```
SELECT Name
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(1) = COUNT(CASE FlagByList WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 END) --counts all rows with Y as Value
       OR COUNT(1) = COUNT(CASE WHEN FlagByList  IS NULL THEN 1 END);  --counts all rows with NULL as value
```

Answer (score 1):

With decode

```
 select name from example
    group by Name 
  having  sum(decode( FlagByList, 'Y',1, 0)) = count(*)  
            OR sum(decode(List, NULL, 0, 1)) = count(*)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please make use of the below code. Its working fine with SQL server 2012.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Name char(2),List  char(2) , FlagByList char(2))
INSERT @Table
(Name,List,FlagByList)
VALUES
('A','1','Y'),
('A','2','Y'),
('B','1','Y'),
('B','2','N'),
('C','-','-'),
('C','-','-')

SELECT DISTINCT(Name) FROM @Table WHERE FlagByList ='Y'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT(Name) FROM @Table WHERE FlagByList ='-'
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT(Name) FROM @Table WHERE FlagByList ='N'
```

Comment: I'm not sure if Oracle supports `EXCEPT` but I like how simple this query is.